# Python QC field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I am new to Python and am trying to run a simple QA/QC on a particular set of fields.

I basically want to verify that fields x and y add up to z, I may have to incorporate rounding since a small difference doesn't make a difference and will throw off my results.  This is what I have currently and it is not processing:

```
def Qcontrol(check):
  if (!Forest_Acres! + !NonForest_Acres!) = !ACRES!:
     return 0
  else:
    return 1

Qcontrol(!check!)
```

all fields are double. **Also need to compensate for Nulls in Forest and Non_forest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put all the fields needed for the calculation as arguments. Also the output field does not need to be mentioned and the equality test is ==, not = (which is for setting a value). Finally, verify your indentations, they are of paramount importance in Python (your second "return" was not well indented)

this will look like this

```
def Qcontrol(f_acre, nf_acre, tot):
    if (f_acre + nf_acre) == tot:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

called:

```
Qcontrol(!Forest_Acres!, !NonForest_Acres!, !ACRES!)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, pretty much what im looking for. Forgot to mention I have <null> values in some of the fields which is outputting <null> altogether. Ex. <null> forest, 100 nonforest == <null>

Comment: null values can be handled with, e.g.  "if f_acre is None:"

Comment: @user29863 Now that you have remembered I recommend that you edit your Question to include this additional requirement.  You will also need to specify how you wish nulls to be handled e.g. change them to 0 to let calculation proceed, output null or something like -9999 as result, etc

Comment: I will edit to include the additional requirement, I am still a little unclear as to how to handle the null values. I understand I need an "if" statement but is a "then" included afterward? Please forgive my noobness...

Comment: Python does not use "then" but is based on the indentation. See Python tutorial for this.

Comment: You mentioned "compensate null", but as @PolyGeo said you need to give more information about the output in case of null values. Please add more details.

Comment: I need to change them to 0

Comment: You can see my answer below on how to handle null values...

Answer (score 1):

You could write this to loop through each record in the feature class or table using the following:

```
import arcpy

# Creates a update cursor
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor('FEATURE CLASS NAME or TABLE NAME')

# Loops through records
for row in cur:
   # if they are equal (after rounding) - calcs QControl to 0
   if round(row.FOREST_ACRES,0) + round(row.NONFOREST_ACRES,0) == round(row.ACRES,0):
        row.QControl = 0
   # if they are different - calcs QControl to 1
   else:
        row.QControl = 1
   cur.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle null values, use this... (Python as parser, no need to use Code Block...)

```
0 if (!Forest_Acres! or 0 + !NonForest_Acres! or 0) == !ACRES! or 0 else 1
```